# Is there a switchable logging for ClojureScript? (log4j style logging for ClojureScript)

Tags: logging, clojurescript

I want a way of doing 'switchable' logging for ClojureScript. This is what I've come up with:

First I add some 'flags'

```
(def log-flags #{"func1" "func2" "func3" })
```

Then I write a switchable logging function

```
(defn log-switchable [& flag args] 
  (when (contains? log-flags flag)
    (. js/console (log (str args)))))
```

Then I call it like this:

```
(log-switchable "func2" "here is my log message" 1234)
```

Now these are all just my custom functions. I'm looking for something more standardised.

My question is **Is there a switchable logging (standard or library) for ClojureScript? (log4j style logging for ClojureScript)**

Comment: I implemented something similar (yet not quite this way) in clojurescript with macros. It's similar to black- and white listing as done in timbre: https://github.com/rauhs/klang

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Closure library logging, which is already included in clojurescript so there is no need to add a new dependency.

reference: https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.log.html